# writing a function that takes user input from a string and swaps it with a different character DNA

Tags: python, function, input

I have a DNA problem in which I have to swap letters taken from user input.

As in the argument become Us in the result.

Cs in the argument become Gs in the result.

Gs in the argument become Cs in the result.

Ts in the argument become As in the result.

any other input characters should disappear from the result altogether

example: In [1]: transcribe('ACGT TGCA')

Out[1]: 'UGCAACGU'

I seriously don't know where to start with this one

Comment: you need 2 things: to take input from user, by using [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function and to swap letters, by using [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method.

Comment: On what basis is the blank space between ACGT and TGCA going to be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through the input string, read the character that comes out and then create a new string depending on needs. Or take the original string and replace as needed like mentioned in the comments.

A very basic version of that could look like this:

```
RESULT = ""
    for character in input:
        if character == "A":
            RESULT = RESULT + "U"
        elif character == "C":
            RESULT = RESULT + "G"
        elif character == "G":
            RESULT = RESULT + "C"
        elif character == "T":
            RESULT = RESULT + "A"
```

Ideally you want to make it cleaner, but hopefully this gives you enough of an idea to continue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).